# Draw route and get distance from coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

we're working on a web app for fleet management.
We collect coordinates from vehicles and we would like to show a map with the "history" routes and the km traveled.

Problem is that the position sometimes is out of the road, so route API shows a strange route. This translates into a "drawn route" with a strange path and a lot of km more. Another problem is that the route is the one currently suggested, for example for work in progress

We are also trying to use polylines but that means that the line does not follow the road (ex curved road).

Do you have any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap for snapping the gps locations to the roads and interpolating the gps locations to account for roads that are not straight.

Comment: It certainly isn't straightforward making the roads API work for actual GPS coordinates.

Comment: Hi,
snapping seems to be a good start.
I'll try with the coordinates we have.
In the meantime, thanks for the tip